# How to get the checkbox tint color value in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, colors, tint

I have **set** the tint color of checkbox with following code:

```
checkBox.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_green_color)));
```

Now i want to **get** the tint color value from the same checkbox.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your response and because you are new here I just recall you an important thing that please upvote the answer if you found any answer useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of you have just put a **single-state-color** by inserting it into `ColorStateList` (`ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_green_color)`) so you can get the tint color by

```
checkBox.getButtonTintList().getDefaultColor()
```

And if you use a **multi-state-colored** `ColorStateList` then you can get the corresponded  color of a specific state by

```
checkBox.getButtonTintList().getColorForState(stateSet,checkBox.getButtonTintList().getDefaultColor());
```

If you find any trouble understanding how to get color if you have **multi-state-colored** `ColorStateList` then visit [this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.content.res.ColorStateList&method=getColorForState) for a more clear understanding.